# Any pros and cons on relocating register on the ceiling?

Tags: furnace, air-conditioning, register

I need to relocate a Heat/AC register (*Labeled 2*)

I am planning to move it to  new location (*Labeled 3*), kind of in the middle of the room on the ceiling.

At the same time I think I need to move the bathroom fan from (*Labeled 1*) to new location (*Labeled4*) in order to better cover the shower area where the humidity will be.

I know that the new location of the register is not ideal but I do not have another option.

Do you foresee any issues with this plan ?

The only other possible option would be to install it on the wall that is behind the viewer but since the duct is 4" in diameter it wont fit in the internal partition wall that separates the bathroom from a hallway.

[image]

Comment: having the heat come from the ceiling might make the bathroom relatively cool.

Comment: yeah I know but what can I do ? As you can see the vent goes across the joists. 
It was fine where is was because there was a pedestal sing there just next to is and the bath tun was long the wall where the vanity is right now. With the shower in the new position I am seeing an issue with keeping the register where it is
I might try to reroute it toward the right and drop it just behind the glass door but it will completely section the studs and I will need to dig a channel through the insulation to make room for this giant duct

Comment: you can use a flat rectangular or oval duct inside stud walls.

Comment: I was looking into that solution last night...looking for the fittings now. I just looked at the diagram and I don't think it will be possible as I have to run a plumbing vent (2" OD) across that same wall horizontally. So unless the rectangular can be 1.5"x whatever I don't see that working. I am afraid that having plumbing and ducts running horizontally there might weaken that framing and the drywall and the tiles will end up falling off the wall because of lack of support at the back

Answer (score -1):

You may “short circuit” the supply and exhaust registers.

When the supply register is blowing, it assists in keeping the mirror dry. We know the exhaust fan REMOVES the condensation, but the supply will also help keep the mirror dry.

Comment: there is no exhaust register in this bathroom
the entire basement has only one exhaust register :-( and that is on the hallway

Comment: The exhaust fan will suck the heat out and the bathroom may feel cold with the duct in the ceiling especially if you move the exhaust right next to the vent.

Comment: You indicate that #1 is going to move to location #4. Please clarify if the register is not in the room.

Comment: the bathroom has one AC vent and one bathroom fan. The AC system has no way to suck air out of the room (no return duct) The exhaust pipe for the bathroom fan is at the end of the white pipe you see coming out of the fan box ..it vents outside the house, on the side